# Информация о файле в Javascript

Tags: html, javascript

Добрый день!

Собственно как получить все данные о файле который на данный момент находится в поле **input**? В частности интересует получение **base64** изображения. Буду признателен если кто-нибудь даст ссылку на документацию или объяснит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.google.ru/search?q=File+API — куча инфы по этой теме

```
var el = document.getElementById('input');
el.addEventListener('change', function (){
    var files = el.files; // список выбранных файлов

    files.forEach(function (file){
        console.log(file); // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
        var Reader = new FileReader;
        Reader.onload = function (evt){
              console.log(evt.result); // DataURL
        };
        Reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}, false);
```